# A basic doubt on proof of functional limits

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

In an analysis book, to prove that $\lim_{x \to 1}t(x)$ does not exist for a function $t(x)$ defined as follows : 
$$
t(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 &\mbox{if } x =0,\\
\frac{1}{n} &\mbox{if } x = \frac{m}{n} \in \mathbb Q^+,\\
0 & \mbox{if } x \notin \mathbb Q.
\end{cases}
$$

the hint given as given $\epsilon > 0$, consider the set of points $\{x \in \Bbb R : t(x) \geq \epsilon\}$ and it asks to argue that all the points in the set are isolated. I could not understand why the proof of this will prove that $\lim_{x \to 1}t(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: Are you sure about what is being proved?  The limit exists, and showing that those points are isolated will help you prove it.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: consider two sequence converging to 1, a) the constant sequence of all 1's b) sequence of irrationals converging to 1. for these two sequences $t(x_n)$ is not same. So, the limit does not exist.

Comment: That does not show that the limit does not exist (it does exist), that shows that the function is not continuous at $1$.  For the limit to be $L$ it suffices that for each sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $1$ such that $x_n\neq 1$ for all $n$, you have $t(x_n)\to L$.  The value of $t(1)$ does not affect the limit of $t(x)$ as $x\to 1$.  In this case you can see that $L=0$ if it exists, but there is some work to prove that the limit is in fact $0$.